# When to prefer passing State<T> vs T itself

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Are there any circumstances in which one should prefer one of these alternatives over the other?

```
@Composable
fun <T> Foo(data: State<T>) { ... }
```

compared to

```
@Composable
fun <T> Foo(data: T) { ... }
```

Or with mutable states,

```
@Composable
fun <T> Foo(data: MutableState<T>) { ... }
```

compared to

```
@Composable
fun <T> Foo(data: T, setData: (T) -> Unit) { ... }
```

Clearly one advantage of having a setData lambda is you can intercept the set operation, but I'm more interested from a Compose perspective. Are there any implications for the compose compiler or how recomposition will work?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer

```
@Composable
fun <T> Foo(data: T) { ... }
```

and

```
@Composable
fun <T> Foo(data: T, setData: (T) -> Unit) { ... }
```

over their respective counter parts. Reasons are:

- For the first one, In case you have to change `State` data structure in future, you have to refactor all the `Composable` for
  actually no reason, as `State<T>` does not bring any extra
  accessibility to your `Composable`. Besides, in the sample projects
  and live demo from Google, I have always seen them to use `T`
- For the second one, suppose you are using the `MutableState` two or more composable, for example `ComposableA` and `ComposableB`, both composable can change each others state if they make any update to `MutableState` which might create issues in some situation. If `ComposableP` is their least common parent, I would prefer declaring `MutableState` in the parent and pass `T` and callbacks to the `ComposableA` and `ComposableB`. You can compare it `State Hoisting`

Comment: This answer feels quite vague, e.g. "which might create issues in some situation". I agree with it's a good thing to avoid reliance on the `State<T>` type, but overall I'd like more citations/sources.